# how can i make an image texture invisible and another one visible with keyframes

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, keyframes, visibility

I'm trying to make an image texture become invisible and another one become visible at a specific point in time for an animation. here's the thing though... I cant use a mix shader because you cant plug a mix shader into a color input (in this case principle BSDF)

[image]

blend file: https://mega.nz/file/2pUyHZ4A#nCIns33IlpGmRoMlzMoj26Gf3zuIpmoGfgVY_8Xvazo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by mixing the images with a *MixRGB Node*, and using a *Greater Than (Math) Node* in combination with the frame number provided by a *Value Node* with `#frame` written as the input. The example below switches the images at frame 50:

[image: Mix]

If you want it to switch back (as indicated in your comment), you can use the Node arrangement below which uses both a *Lesser Than* and a *Greater Than* to give further control. I think the setup below is correct, but I can't test because you didn't pack any images - if it's wrong, fixing it should only be a matter of switching input positions.

[image: Fix]

Comment: that works but since i need to make the original image reappear 1 or 2 frames after (like blinking which is something I should have included in the post). i don't see a way to make it appear right after

Comment: I added another example to my answer.

Comment: yeah sorry about that. i thought blender packed the textures. tried a bunch or rearrangements but still couldn't get it to work. so here are the textures https://mega.nz/folder/PxEBXArJ#fCcxtvQZsB_ns3t6xVInBQ

Comment: The 2 images you posted (_m_eyelid_alb.0_, and _m_eyelid_alb.3_) are identical (aside from resolution), could this be the root of your problem?

Comment: yeah it was an issue with that. so I assume to make more blinking later I would just add more math and mixRGB nodes?